# How to read /dev/urandom to an array

Tags: c, random, key

I have a C program that read random number from /dev/urandom to a array as a 256 bits key, but it seems not thing read. What happen to my program?

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LEN 32 // 256 bits
void main()
{

    unsigned char *key = (unsigned char *) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*LEN);
    FILE* random = fopen("/dev/urandom", "r");
    fread(key, sizeof(unsigned char)*LEN, 1, random);
    fclose(random);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work because you use `void main` instead of `int main` and you don't check if `fopen` returns `NULL`. To fix it, do those things and then print the array.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: void main() is not a valid signature for main. C standard have ”int main(void)” and ”int main(int argc, char * argv[])” as the only ones who are valid.

Comment: How do you know that nothing is read?

Comment: `sizeof (unsigned char)` is, by definition, `1`.

Comment: @Fredrik `sizeof( char )` is **not** "at least 1".  [It **is** 1, and not more than 1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.4p4): "When sizeof is applied to an operand that has type char, unsigned char, or signed char, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is 1."

Comment: @Fredrik: read [C11 6.2.6.1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.6.1)p3 and the associated footnote 49.

Comment: See also [C11 §6.5.3.4 The `sizeof` and `_Alignof` operators  ¶4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.4p4): _When `sizeof` is applied to an operand that has type `char`, `unsigned char`, or `signed char`, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is 1._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your instructions at every step:

```
#define LEN 32 // 256 bits

int main(void)
{
    unsigned char *key = malloc( (sizeof(unsigned char)*LEN) + 1);

    if ( NULL == key )
    {
        printf("Error on malloc");
        return -1;
    }

    memset (key, 0, (sizeof(unsigned char)*LEN) + 1 );

    FILE* random = fopen("/dev/urandom", "r");
    if ( NULL == random )
    {
        printf("Error on fopen");
        free (key);
        return -1;
    }

    fread(key, sizeof(unsigned char)*LEN, 1, random);

    printf("|%s|\n", key);

    free (key);
    fclose(random);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("|%s|\n", key);`?  For random bytes from `/dev/urandom`?  That's not a printable string.

Comment: @AndrewHenle That why i add **+1** in malloc, setted to **0** to avoid any undefined behaviour in printf